# We are printing images to a pdf using XSL fo. our aim is to print them in row wise but those are printing in column wise. Any suggestions please

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo" xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="assets">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="one" page-width="216mm" page-height="279mm" margin-top="10mm" margin-bottom="5mm" margin-left="10mm" margin-right="10mm">
                    <fo:region-body column-count="5" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent="1cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" font-size="16pt" text-align="center">
                        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:static-content>
                <!--footer-->
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-family="Arial" text-align="left">All rights reserved.</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" text-align="right">Page <fo:page-number/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
                <!-- body -->
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="assetExport"/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="width" select="@displayValue"/>
    <xsl:template match="assetExport">
        <fo:block-container border-color="#D3D3D3" border-style="solid" border-width=".8px" margin-top="4mm" keep-together.within-column="always" width="36mm" height="56mm" scaling="uniform">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="thumbnail"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="metadata"/>
        </fo:block-container>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="metadata">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="property"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Render the images -->
    <xsl:template match="thumbnail">
        <xsl:variable name="src" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$src = ''">
                <fo:block-container>
                    <fo:block width="30mm" height="40mm" font-weight="bold" font-size="12pt" text-indent="5mm" margin-top="3mm" margin-bottom="2mm" margin-left="2mm" margin-right="2mm">
                        <xsl:text width="30mm" height="40mm">No Preview available</xsl:text>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:block margin-left="2mm" margin-right="2mm" margin-top="0mm">
                    <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:///{$src})" width="32mm" text-align="center" display-align="center" content-width="scale-to-fit" height="32mm" content-height="scale-to-fit" scaling="uniform"/>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Render the metadata WITH Prompt -->
    <xsl:template match="property">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@prompt = 'Expiration Date'">
                <fo:block margin-left="2mm" wrap-option="wrap" width="34mm" height="30mm" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" color="black">
                    <xsl:value-of select="(concat('Expiration Date: ',substring(child::property-value/attribute::displayValue,0,11)))"/>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:block margin-left="2mm" wrap-option="wrap" width="34mm" height="30mm" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" color="black">
                    <xsl:value-of select="attribute::prompt"/>
                    <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="child::property-value/attribute::displayValue"/>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your source XML?  Which formatter are you using?